# while (have_posts()) : the_post(); repeating the same post over and over?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am having an issue with this little snippet.  Basically it is grabbing one post in the current-releases category and repeatedly displaying it instead of grabbing and displaying the first 3.  Any thoughts?  I'm sure its a stupid missed " or something.

```
    global $query_string;

    query_posts( array(
    'showposts'  => 3,
    'cat' => 'current-releases'
) );

    echo '<div class="related-posts">';

    while (have_posts()) : the_post();
       echo '<div class="related-album">'.the_post_thumbnail('large');
        echo ' '.the_title();
       echo '</div>';
    endwhile;

    echo '</div>';
```

Comment: `if(x) while(x) ... endwhile endif` is totally redundant - you only need the `while`.

Comment: I have removed the If statement altogether and the issue still exists but thank you for the cleanup.

Comment: Brandon, I know very little of PHP or Wordpress, I didn't expect it to solve your problem (otherwise it would have been an answer rather than a comment). I'm just OCD when it comes to code cleanliness :-)

Comment: Oh yeah I understand just added that bit so anyone else reading knows the issue still exists.  Thank you as I like to keep the code as clean as possible when I can.

Comment: `echo ' '.the_title();` may need to be `echo ' '.the_title('','',FALSE);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `wp_reset_query();` after the `endwhile`. Please follow the function reference where you can see the example snippet.

[https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_reset_query/](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_query)

Answer (score 0):

Your query_posts options need to be formatted as an array:

```
query_posts( array(
    'showposts'  => 3,
    'cat' => 'current-releases'
) );
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I updated the question to have it reflect your answer and the issue still exists on my query.  It keeps showing the same one over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

`query_posts` shouldn't be used. I'd start by swapping that out. Remember that by doing so you'll need to update your loop as well.

```
$related_posts = new WP_Query( array(
    'posts_per_page'  => 3,
    'cat' => 'current-releases',
    'no_found_rows' => true,
) );

// we don't want any output if no posts found. 
if ( $related_posts->have_posts() ) : 

    echo '<div class="related-posts">';

    while ( $related_posts->have_posts() ) : $related_posts->the_post();
       echo '<div class="related-album">';

       // the_post_thumbnail() and the_title() output, not return
       the_post_thumbnail( 'large' );
       the_title( ' ' ); // I've used ' ' as the before arg since your original code did that.

       echo '</div>';
    endwhile;

endif;
```